# cleaning CPU's from cooling paste

Tags: cpu, cleaning

> I ask this question is because sometimes CPU's are carried by air planes and the cooling paste may pop out from the cover hole because of the different air pressures in an airplane.

is anyone experienced with cleaning CPU's from cooling paste.
In particular the tiny hole that the CPU's cover has.
 How can I remove the paste from this hole.
Are there tools to do this?

See hole in top left:

[image]

This CPU was cleaned, but when it was unpacked after air transport, it looked like this:

[image]

Comment: welcome to superuser:- a hair drier may re-heat it so it can then be moved, a glue removal gun or liquid. falling that i was always told to use a fork and spoon with pasta (sorry), again welcome to superuser

Comment: A hole in your CPU? That doesn’t sound right. What CPU is it, exactly?

Comment: Hi Daniel , intel xeon e5 serie fe. e5-2620

Comment: Have you actually experienced this problem or is it just a theoretical concern?  Where is the cover hole you're referring to? (the laptop case?  CPU?  Heat sink?)  Change in air pressure shouldn't affect thermal paste.  Can you add a snapshot of what you're referring to?  (just post a link to it at a sharing site like imgur.com).

Comment: Ok here are some pictures. 1 you can see the hole left above. 2 this cpu was cleaned but when it was unpacked after air transport, it looked like this. https://imgur.com/a/Gplch6m

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use alcohol wipes when cleaning thermal past from the CPU and cooler.

Don't worry about the little hole on the CPU its okay if thermal paste gets in there but if you do want to remove it i suggest using a small hair pin or something similar to get it out.

Here are some links to other sites
   [Link1](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2971963/xeon-1650-small-hole-thermal-grease.html) | [Link2](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/820213-why-is-there-a-hole-in-my-cpu-is-this-normal/) with similar questions if you're still worried.